# Why this snippet is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           $("#button").submit(function() {  
            {
            var email_id=document.getElementById('textfield').value;
            var password=document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
            var utype=document.getElementById("utype").value;
    var url="login_check.jsp?&email_id="+encodeURIComponent(email_id)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password)+"&utype="+encodeURIComponent(utype);
            $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action',url);  
        alert(document.form1.action);    
        }
        });
```

on the click of submit button with id="button" an alert dialog box should appear with the url..... Why the above code is not working? Please help

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Why all this mixing of jQuery and DOM-methods?

Comment: since you are already using jquery, why don't you use jquery apis like serialize

Comment: Extra tip: do not put a password in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() { 
        var email_id=document.getElementById('textfield').value;
        var password=document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
        var utype=document.getElementById("utype").value;
        var url="login_check.jsp?&email_id="+encodeURIComponent(email_id)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password)+"&utype="+encodeURIComponent(utype);
        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action',url);  
        alert(document.form1.action);    
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8pN/).

=== UPDATE 2 ===

Here a short version:

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" action="login_check.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="email_id">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="text" name="utype">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

JS (is not neccessary if you don't want to do more):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('form').prop('action', "login_check.jsp?" + $('form').serialize());
    });
});
```

And an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tMabu/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra opening bracket just after the submit listener's anonymous function argument is declared.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           $("#button").submit(function() {  
            var email_id=document.getElementById('textfield').value;
            var password=document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
            var utype=document.getElementById("utype").value;
    var url="login_check.jsp?&email_id="+encodeURIComponent(email_id)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password)+"&utype="+encodeURIComponent(utype);
            $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action',url);  
        alert(document.form1.action);    
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

- From the bottom 2nd brace(}) you didn't closed well.
- You should write like this "})" instead of "}".
- Proper closing is important Enjoy the code